# Executing python script with pdflatex using PHP on Ubuntu webserver?

Tags: python, php, webserver, pdflatex

I am trying to execute a python script which uses pdflatex using php. Running the python script via command line works well.

But if I try to call it with php, it throws this error:

> I can't write on file mylatex.log'. (Press Enter to retry, or
> Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.log') Please type
> another transcript file name: ! Emergency stop ! ==> Fatal error
> occurred, no output PDF file produced!

So there seems to be a permission error.

This is the way I am trying to call the php file:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 /home/ubuntu/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

The mylatex.log file has 777 permission as a test.

Is there a way to execute a python script which uses a library like pdflatex?

Comment: I would suggest testing out the python script from another location on the command line, to make sure it works. For instance, if you normally test it in `/home/myuser`, try from `/var/www/` or maybe just `/`. I have a feeling that you may be using a relative path instead of an absolute path to the mylatex.log.

Comment: I copied the folder to /var/www and adapted the path. But the error still exists.

Comment: No, I wouldn't suggest copying the folder anywhere. The issue is most likely with the python script and file paths, which is why I suggest testing it out on a different path than where you normally run it on the command line

Comment: Could you explain it a little bit more in detail? I have copied the .py file to another location. I placed the .py file in a folder with a .tex file. So this folder is copied, not the folder of pdflatex

Comment: `cd /; python3 /home/ubuntu/test.py` -- Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by adding the php file to the same directory as the python file. Then it works. There seems to be a problem to call pdflatex in a different directory. Thanks for the help.